# Maximum trigger depth exceeded&Task assign to Multiple user

Tags: trigger

In Salesforce, when creating a task record, we could assign it to multiple users. This creates multiple 'Same' Task records to different users.

I am creating a trigger so that whenever a task record is updated, all its siblings are updated.

I encountered "Maximum trigger depth exceeded" error when I tested my trigger.

```
trigger AR_closeSameTask on Task (after update) {

// Get all the task fields 
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> taskFieldMap=Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.getMap();
List<Schema.SObjectField> taskFields=taskFieldMap.values();
List<String> taskAPIFieldNames=new List<String>();

// Go through all the task fields 
For(Schema.SObjectField s: taskFields)
{
    taskAPIFieldNames.add(s.getDescribe().getName());
}       
    //Same Tasks List
List<Task> sameTasks=new List<Task>();
for(Task t : Trigger.new)
{
        Boolean isChanged=false;        
        Task oldt=Trigger.oldMap.get(t.Id);                   
        for(String field:taskAPIFieldNames)
        {
            if(t.get(field)!=oldt.get(field))
            {
                isChanged=true;
                break;
            }
        }        
    if(isChanged)
    {        
        //criteria to find same task: Categories__c,Subject,whatid,whoid,createddate 
        sameTasks=[select Status,createddate,OwnerId,Id from Task
                       where Categories__c=:t.Categories__c and Subject=:t.Subject and 
                       whatid=:t.WhatId and whoid=:t.WhoId and Id!=:t.Id];                                           
            For(Task st : sameTasks){                    
                if(st.CreatedDate.date()==t.CreatedDate.date()&&st.CreatedDate.hour()==t.CreatedDate.hour()&&
                   st.CreatedDate.minute()==t.CreatedDate.minute()){                        
                    String ownerid=st.OwnerId;
                    String Id=st.Id;
                    st=t.clone(false,true);
                    st.OwnerId=ownerid;
                    st.Id=Id;
            }   
            update sameTasks;            
    }
    }




}
}


@isTest
public class AR_Test_closeSameTask {
@isTest
static void testmethod1()
{

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    List<User> newUsers=new List<User>();
    For(integer i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        String newemail=i+'standarduser@testorg.com';
        String newuserName=i+'standarduser@testorg.com';
        User newUser = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email=newemail, 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=newuserName);
        newUsers.add(newUser);
    }

    insert newUsers;
    System.debug('total user: '+newUsers.size());



    Account a=new Account(name='a');
    insert a;
    String AccountID=[select id from Account where name='a'].Id;
    Contact c=new Contact(firstname='f',lastname='l');
    insert c;
    String ContactId=[Select id from Contact where firstname='f'].Id;

    //all the users can be assinged to task
    //List<User> users=[select id from User];        
    List<Task> tsks=new List<Task>();

    //500 multiple users tasks
    For(Integer i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        For(User u : newUsers){
            Task t=new Task(subject='Admin Call',Categories__c='Administration',whatId=AccountID,whoid=ContactId,ownerId=u.id);
            tsks.add(t);
        }
    }
    System.debug(tsks.size());
    insert tsks;

    tsks=[select Status from Task];
    System.debug(tsks.size());
    Task updatedTask=tsks[0];
    updatedTask.Status='Completed';
    update updatedTask;
    tsks=[select Status,createddate from Task];
    For(Task t: tsks)
    {
        System.debug(t.createddate);
    }
    tsks=[select Status from Task where Status='Completed'];

    System.assertEquals(50, tsks.size());

}
```

}

Can you share some light to me?

Answer (score 1):

After the if statement below, you keep running the query and updating the results all within your `for(Task t : Trigger.new){` loop which causes it to get caught in an infinite loop because it keeps updating itself.

```
if(isChanged)
{        
    //criteria to find same task: Categories__c,Subject,whatid,whoid,createddate 
    sameTasks=[select Status,createddate,OwnerId,Id from Task
                   where Categories__c=:t.Categories__c and Subject=:t.Subject and 
                   whatid=:t.WhatId and whoid=:t.WhoId and Id!=:t.Id];                                           
        For(Task st : sameTasks){                    
            if(st.CreatedDate.date()==t.CreatedDate.date()&&st.CreatedDate.hour()==t.CreatedDate.hour()&&
               st.CreatedDate.minute()==t.CreatedDate.minute()){                        
                String ownerid=st.OwnerId;
                String Id=st.Id;
                st=t.clone(false,true);
                st.OwnerId=ownerid;
                st.Id=Id;
        }   
        update sameTasks;
```

Move `update sameTasks;` to outside the outer for loop and that should solve your issue with maximum trigger depth due to recursion.